# Alternative to UISplitViewController?

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have to make an app for iPad which requires a `UISplitViewController`- like view but with extra navigation bars on the top. Unfortunately, the native `UISplitViewController` does not have support for this. As an example of what I want, consider the apple documentation site which looks like:

[image: What I want]

But what `UISplitViewController` offers is a part of it (Master-Detail controllers only):

[image: What we're given]

So my question is: What is the best way to do this? Should I subclass `UISplitViewController`(which, I'm a little less confident of) or should I use `loadNibNamed:` or is there some open-source project out there?

**Edit** I need to put images, buttons and a search-bar in the extra top bar.

Comment: Do you want the navigation bar at the top to be unified? Or you're ok with individual bars?

Comment: I think either would work well for me. The only requirement is an extra view(would be preferable instead of a navigation bar) above the nav bar of split view

Answer (score 1):

What you need it [`MGSplitViewController`](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController/). It allows you to push the split view controller inside a navigation controller.
You can also accomplish what you require by digging in the view hierarchy and planting your view there, but `MGSplitViewController` would be more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently developed a library and published on gitHub for IOS devices both iPhone and iPad. It's act like an UISplitViewController but there ara more customization option that you can use. https://github.com/ytur/USController